# Docker Pull Output Weird

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-registry

When I pull normally using `docker pull <image-name>` my output looks like this
[image: good_output]

When I pull using `docker-compose up` my output looks like this
[image]

They are both pulling/using the same image. They both work in the end but the output of the first looks a lot better than the second. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker-compose was called Fig before it was acquired by Docker in 2014. It doesn't share codebase with docker. It's actually built using Python where as Docker is in Go.

You could open an issue at Github to request that they make both more consistent. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues